# Build a photoshop script to add a text layer to the batch of photos

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, photoshop, photoshop-script

Note : My photoshop is cs6
I am ordered to create a script that works on bunch of photo and add a text for every single photo.

I have a data like this (text list notepad example) :
'logo file'
'model number'
'model number'

```
logo accuride.jpg
acc-899
acc-567
acc-776
logo bocsh.jpg
boc-777
boc-699
boc-563
logo dell.jpg
65777
89992
45663
```

Basically, I already imagine the step :
1. Locate where the notepad (the list)
2. Read and Parse the list. To know what logo and what to write
3. Took a photo on library (ie. logo accuride.jpg)
4. Put in the active document layer
5. Create new text layer, place on top of the logo
6. Export as jpg, rename as same as model number
7. delete all layer or close the document
8. repeat from step 1

[from this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WeRczNvujL-SIZ5Ouy3yyn63tQkq81_y/view?usp=sharing)
[to this - goal](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16zdkKzQ0ZmgHi2qY80TUVv8mQwFwdYgm/view?usp=sharing)

Here is what i have done :

```
var doc = activeDocument  
var textFile = new File(Folder.desktop+ '/model-number.txt');  
var list = readText (textFile).split('\n'); 

 for (var j = 0; i<list.length; i++) {
     if (list[j].some("logo")) { //jika list j contain kata "logo" maka :

        var artLayerRef = doc.artLayers.add()  
        artLayerRef.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;  
        var textItemRef = artLayerRef.textItem;  
        textItemRef.contents = list[i]  
     }
 }

 function readText(file){  
     if (textFile.exists) {  
    textFile.encoding = "ANSI";  
    textFile.lineFeed = "unix";  
    textFile.open("r", "TEXT", "????");  
    var str = textFile.read();  
    textFile.close();  
    return str;  
    }  
}
```

And the truth is, i am very newbie with this js, especially for photoshop scripting. Usually I am create a vba script to support my collage.
I spend more than 2 hour ONLY to figure how to import image into an active document layer and still no luck.
I also imagine to use vba to call photoshop application. So the data came from table on my workbook. But now, only to import an image makes me dizzy.

I forgot to ask :
1. How do I import an image into a layer of active document?
2. How to check substring from array of string in js? Like when i found word "logo*" then do if statement.

I am very appreciate any solution, assistance and help from you.
Thanks.

Yuri

Comment: What is your question exactly? Code for most of the steps you need can be found in the Photoshop JS References pdf (https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2019.pdf), could you please rewrite your question so it wouldn't look like you want someone to write a script for you? p.s. Note that `.some()` won't work in Photoshop without polyfill, PS uses a very old version of JS

Comment: ok, add specific question. Then what should i used to check a substring of array? @SergeyKritskiy

Comment: that documentation is very painful for me. Is there any good website that guide someone for this? or what function should i use? Actually, i need a site that give some example rather just show me the technical words. im using cs6 btw @SergeyKritskiy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a Photoshop plugin called [ScriptListener](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html#id_68969), after you install it, Photoshop will start to write most of the actions you do in Photoshop as Action Manager Javascript Code. That's one of the ways to find code for things you can't find in the Scripting References pdf. For example to import an image, you can do `File > Place Embedded`, load a selection to determine its bounding box, crop to this selection and deselect. These actions will give you this code in ScriptingListenerJS.log on your desktop:

```
// =======================================================
var idPlc = charIDToTypeID( "Plc " );
    var desc7 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idIdnt = charIDToTypeID( "Idnt" );
    desc7.putInteger( idIdnt, 12 );
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    desc7.putPath( idnull, new File( "/C/Users/Sergey Kritskiy/Desktop/temp/triangles.png" ) );
    var idFTcs = charIDToTypeID( "FTcs" );
    var idQCSt = charIDToTypeID( "QCSt" );
    var idQcsa = charIDToTypeID( "Qcsa" );
    desc7.putEnumerated( idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsa );
    var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
        var desc8 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc8.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idPxl, 0.000000 );
        var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
        var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
        desc8.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idPxl, 0.000000 );
    var idOfst = charIDToTypeID( "Ofst" );
    desc7.putObject( idOfst, idOfst, desc8 );
executeAction( idPlc, desc7, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc9 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref1 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var idfsel = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
        ref1.putProperty( idChnl, idfsel );
    desc9.putReference( idnull, ref1 );
    var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
        var ref2 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var idTrsp = charIDToTypeID( "Trsp" );
        ref2.putEnumerated( idChnl, idChnl, idTrsp );
    desc9.putReference( idT, ref2 );
executeAction( idsetd, desc9, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idCrop = charIDToTypeID( "Crop" );
    var desc11 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idDlt = charIDToTypeID( "Dlt " );
    desc11.putBoolean( idDlt, true );
executeAction( idCrop, desc11, DialogModes.NO );

// =======================================================
var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc13 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref3 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var idfsel = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
        ref3.putProperty( idChnl, idfsel );
    desc13.putReference( idnull, ref3 );
    var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
    var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
    var idNone = charIDToTypeID( "None" );
    desc13.putEnumerated( idT, idOrdn, idNone );
executeAction( idsetd, desc13, DialogModes.NO );
```

It's quite hard to read, there're utilities that help to beautify it a little bit (like `SLCFix.js` in [xbytor's xtools](http://ps-scripts.sourceforge.net/xtools.html)), but it does the job and you can see the strings you need to replace to put make a function that'd place a file in a document.

2) for your strings and logos, I guess there're different ways of doing this, I'd do it like this:

```
var list = readText(textFile).split('\n'),
    curLogo = "",
    logos = {};

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    var curLine = list[i].match(/logo.*\.jpg/);
    if (curLine != null)
    {
        curLogo = list[i];
        logos[curLogo] = [];
    }
    else
    {
        logos[curLogo].push(list[i])
    }
}
```

this will give you an object like this which you can use later

```
// {
//     "logo accuride.jpg": [
//         "acc-899",
//         "acc-567",
//         "acc-776"
//     ],
//     "logo bocsh.jpg": [
//         "boc-777",
//         "boc-699",
//         "boc-563"
//     ],
//     "logo dell.jpg": [
//         "65777",
//         "89992",
//         "45663"
//     ]
// }

for (var logo in logos)
{
    $.writeln(logo) // logo accuride.jpg
    $.writeln(logos[logo].length) // 3
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Hmm. Its like array in array . Am i right? how to get "logo bocsh.jpg" value? How to get "boc-777" value? And What does logos[logo].length mean? Why return 3? is that count how many model number inside?

Comment: That's a javascript object. To learn basics of the language I'd recommend to get through a course on something like a codeacademy or learn-js.org: this won't take much time, otherwise it's going to be really difficult.

Comment: Hi dude, I am having problem to use push() method. PS detect it as undefined. I also try to use unshift() but no good result. Is there any other way to "push" the array?

Comment: when try to compile with browser (as html), it works well. i could make the array and call it. But it seems like PS doesn't support this kind of method. So, do you have any idea how to "push" the array?

Comment: Really? I spend more than 2 hour to figure this. I follow as your guidance. As I said, i try to compile with browser and its ok. I already tried to use variable, another method, etc. Please kindly see my gist : https://gist.github.com/spartacruz/5370521b84544980e413e073cdd88387

Comment: The truth is, since i saw your answer, i realize that I have made a huge progress. And i believe there is a few obstacle before i reach my goal. So, i would like to say thank you and please kindly help me.

Comment: `.push()` works fine for me in your code. Maybe the problem is in the files you include, I don't have them

Comment: I am absolutely sure about 4 external js, that there is no error in them. As information, I already succeed to import, add text, save as jpg, and delete 2 added layer for just 1 click run. But now, i am having difficulties to iterate it for huge data. And this `.push` hell now makes me crazy.

Comment: Are you using CC edition? Does it available for CS6 also? I am sure there is nothing wrong with my 4 external. But, if you want to see it, i already update my gist. https://gist.github.com/spartacruz/5370521b84544980e413e073cdd88387 Please have a look. Your comment is very worth for me.